# Namespace for official docker hub images in the docker hub api

Tags: dockerhub

What is the namespace of official docker hub images, e.g. alpine? What doesn't work (error 404) is:

- https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/_/repositories/alpine/tags/3
- https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/alpine/repositories/alpine/tags/3
- https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/alpine/tags/3
- https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/repositories/alpine/tags/3

Comment: On this url: https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/alpine, it says `"namespace": "alpine"`  for all results. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jeppe it is, but sadly it's wrong: 
```{
    "message": "httperror 404: object not found",
    "errinfo": {
        "namespace": "alpine",
        "repository": "alpine",
        "tag": "3"
    }
}
``` when it clearly exists: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/alpine/3/images/sha256-25fad2a32ad1f6f510e528448ae1ec69a28ef81916a004d3629874104f8a7f70?context=explore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `library` as namespace:

https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/library/repositories/alpine/tags/3